# The meaning of 'Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory' upon running Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, posix

Tensorflow 2.9.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 with CUDA 11.2 keeps writing to the stdout the following error whenever I try to build a few layers:

```
2022-06-05 08:32:29.319040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
2022-06-05 08:32:29.527708: I tensorflow/core/platform/default/subprocess.cc:304] Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory
```

No traceback or anything. The model seems to build normally, though, but I wonder if there are any performance implications.

What can be the reason of this error? Is there a way to increase the verbosity of the output without rebuilding the Tensorflow binary?

Comment: Hi @Mike, Tensorflow 2.9 is compatible with CUDA 11.2 according to the tested build configurations. Please downgrade CUDA 11.7 to 11.2 and try again.

Comment: @Tfer3 Problem repeats on CUDA 11.2

Comment: are you by any chance running tensorflow inside a nspawn container?

Comment: @ghylander, nope

Comment: I too have this problem, I suspected it was caused by a container not having the required permissions, but you seem to have this problem too. I've been looking into it for a bit now, but as the trainings seems to carry on without issue I've not invested too much time in it. If you do happen to find out the cause please share it. Building tensorflow from source to add some prints here and there for debug pursposes is not an option for me.

Comment: Any news on this one? I have similar problem on WSL2. Training keeps running, but I suspect because of that the paralelism does not work effectively.

Answer (score 11):

Execute

```
$ export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin"
```

before starting your cPython notebook kernel / interpreter.

Comment: This worked, thanks! What is the reasoning behind?

Comment: You told me that during CUDA compilation the compiler reported `cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory`. It wants to spawn compiler tools. It appeared you had not correctly installed those tools, had not updated `.bash_profile` to include them in $PATH, so I proposed a workaround for the partially completed install.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue with TensorFlow on WSL2, the following fixed it for me:

*As a note, I initially had a **Permission Denied** error, which I think was due to a newer version of CUDA that I had installed - after uninstalling that, I got the same **No such file or directory** error.*

First, ensure you have the correct version of CUDA and cuDNN that TensorFlow requires installed.

Secondly, make sure to change the `libcuda.so` and `libcuda.so.1` files to be symlinks of `libcuda.so.1.1` (which CUDA doesn't do for you, it just makes copies of the files) - this has to be done on Windows, and should automatically show up in your WSL installations. A guide can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5663#issuecomment-1068499676).

Thirdly, make sure to follow the instructions on the [NVIDIA page about GPU with WSL](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#cuda-support-for-wsl-2). I found them to be a tad weird and hard to read, but basically, it tells you to:

- Update your GPU drivers on Windows (just the newest Game Ready Driver).
- Update your WSL kernel (and for good measure let's run the distribution using version 2 and not 1).
- Install the correct version of `cuda-toolkit` on WSL, that matches with the version that you have installed on Windows - download instructions can be found [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_network), just be sure to change the version to the one TensorFlow requires that you have installed on Windows.